# Postman. Кнопка отправки запроса заблокирована

Tags: postman

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Надо протестировать работу post запроса локально.
Установил Postman
Но он вообще не чего не отправляет. Кнопка отправке заблокирована.

Жму Create a fork появляется сообщение:
Unable to fetch source collection
Error in syncing

Comment: ну во первых вы отправляете не POST а GET.  и если я правильно понял вы используете веб версию POSTMAN'а. Скачайте postman к себе на пк и там уже можно куда угодно отправлять запросы. А так в веб версии вы можете только на локалку отправлять запросы.

Comment: Скрин просто показывает, что кнопка недоступна. Это не вэб версия. Начал тыкать везде, на вкладке Home есть картинка с "вилкой", нажал ее и все заработало.

Comment: а аккаунт зареган?